# Angular: Call method using string value for name

Tags: angularjs

So I have Googled this quite allot today, and I'm afraid the answers I got, did not satisfy the problem I'm facing. I'm trying to call a method within a controller (*controller as syntax*) by only using a string value.

I tried `window['someFunctionName']();` as well as `this['someFunctionName']();` and `vm['someFunctionName']()`, but non of them seems to work. I'm guessing it's because the function I'm calling is not in a global space, but rather local to the controller - example:

```
/* @ngInject */
function dashboardController(logger, _, moment) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.foo = foo

    function getSomeData() {
        // do something....
    }

    function foo() {
        window['getSomeData']();
        this['getSomeData']();
        vm['getSomeData']();
    }

}
```

It feels so trivial ... I could do this soooooo easily in C#, but struggling with something that feels so silly!

Any advice?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want your function to be accessible from your template, you can still create a kind of container for your functions :

```
var functionContainer = {};
functionContainer.getSomeData = function() {
    // Do some stuff
}
```

Going further, your "get data" function should be in a service that you will inject into your controller.

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('getDataService', function(){
    return {
         'getSomeData': getSomeData,
         'getOtherData': getOtherData
    };


    function getSomeData() {
       // do some stuff
    }

    function getOtherData() {
       // do other stuff
    }
});

/* @ngInject */
function dashboardController(logger, _, moment, getDataService) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.foo = function () {
        getDataService['getSomeData']();
    };

}
```

Comment: Sure, but this will make the function public - this is what I ended up doing, but it feels like cheating

Comment: That's the way angular ^1.5 works with the 'controller as' syntax. If you don't want it to be "public", you can use the `$scope` way, but I wouldn't recomment it.

Comment: I totally agree

Comment: maybe I misunderstood your question. What if you bind the function to a new object?
`var functionContainer = {};` `functionContainer.getSomeData = function(){};`

Comment: @RichardBailey answer updated, I hope it'll suit you

Comment: Thanks, will give it a shot... I'm pulling data from local storage, and I'm pretty sure the function will not be persisted. Either way. You gave me another idee. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
/* @ngInject */
function dashboardController(logger, _, moment) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.foo = foo

    vm.getSomeData = function() {
        // do something....
    }

    function foo() {
        vm.getSomeData();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I see - almost like a `get;set;` - in this case only a `get;`

Answer (score 0):

Just simply call `getSomeData();` from foo.
Like:

```
   function foo() {
       getSomeData();
    }
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thmmyh5j/)

Comment: Hmmm - sure that is pretty easy, but not my question. I'm trying to call a method using the string value and not the actual ref to the function.

Comment: okay, then you have to assign it to `vm`, like : `vm.getSomeData = function() {//....);    }`, and then can call it `vm['getSomeData']();`

Comment: Thanks for the response!